# next line should only execute when line above is completely executed do remember that function is called in html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

my.component.html

```
    <button (click)="refresh()">Refresh</button>
```

my.component.ts

```
    refresh() {
        let self = this;
        self.isRefresh = true; //1 ST TYM
        self.getfun();
        self.isRefresh = false; //2ND TYM
    }
```

I WANT THAT:

**when self.getfun(); this function is entirely executed then only execute
self.isRefresh = false; //2ND TYM**

kindly tell me best professional way possible!

i dont wish to make changes in getfun()
as i am working on angular it is asynchronous

Comment: Unless getfun() is an asynchronous function, the next line will not execute until getfun() returns. Is getfun() asynchronous?

Comment: Have you tried using Observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Observables` then check the following snippet

```
getFun(){
    return new Observable((observer)=> {
      //getFun method code goes here 
      observer.complete()
    })
  }

  refresh() {
    let self = this;
    self.isRefresh = true; //1 ST TYM
    this.getFun().subscribe({ complete: () => {
       self.isRefresh = false; //2ND TYM
    }});
  }
```

Comment: is there any other way?